# How to override Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList in magento 2.2.3

Tags: php, magento, filter, magento2, fatal-error

Override the `Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList` in Magento 2.2.3 using plugin. This error came

> PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed
> to ####\Plugin\Model\Layer\FilterList::aroundGetFilters() must
> implement interface
> Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterableAttributeListInterface, instance
> of Closure given, called in
>
> /magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php on line 135 and defined in ####/Plugin/Model/Layer/FilterList.php:70

preference is not working on this file.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please check here on how to ask good questions: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sounds like you've created a closure rather than a class that implements the relevant interface... but without seeing any code it's kinda hard to offer any constructive advice.

Comment: Share the code which you have try.

Comment: I fix this issue.

Comment: I get same issue when I used plugin, @NandhiniNagaraj how to fix?

Comment: Below the post my answer, Verify this @xanka

Comment: thanks u @NandhiniNagaraj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using virtual_type

Once Verify the core file of di.xml arguments passing

#### ..../modulename/extensionmodule/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
 <virtualType name="categoryFilterList" type="ModuleName\ExtensionModule\Model\Layer\FilterList">
    <arguments>
    Your Passing Arguments(same as existing core file - di.xml(core module) passing arguments ).

    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

#### ..../modulename/extensionmodule/Model\Layer

```
<?php

    namespace ModuleName\ExtensionModule\Model\Layer;
    
    /**
     * Override FilterList Class
     */
    class FilterList extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList
    {
        ......Your Code Here......
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is full code to Override Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList this class

I can use **virtualType** method for override instead of **preference**

registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Pradip_LayerModel',
    __DIR__
);
```

etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Pradip_LayerModel" setup_version="0.1.0"/>        
</config>
```

etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <virtualType name="categoryFilterList" type="Pradip\LayerModel\Model\Layer\FilterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="filterableAttributes" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>    
</config>
```

Model/Layer/FilterList.php

```
<?php

    namespace Pradip\LayerModel\Model\Layer;

    /**
     * Override FilterList Class
     */
    class FilterList extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList
    {
        public function getFilters(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer)
        {
            //echo "you can write code changes here"; exit;
            if (!count($this->filters)) {
                $this->filters = [
                    $this->objectManager->create($this->filterTypes[self::CATEGORY_FILTER], ['layer' => $layer]),
                ];
                foreach ($this->filterableAttributes->getList() as $attribute) {
                    $this->filters[] = $this->createAttributeFilter($attribute, $layer);
                }
            }
            return $this->filters;
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot override the class by plugin. If you want to override the class then just use the following code in your di.xml

```
<preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList" type="NAMESPACE\YOUR_MODULE\Model\Layer\FilterList" />
```

If this not works then goto the parent class (Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\FilterList) and check the no of arugments you are sending from __contruct function of your module's FilterList.php. Pass same number of arguments with same order to your parent class. It will work.